# Find a constant c from PDF

Tags: probability, density-function

I have a problem as the following, the question is to solve for c.
[image]

I let the equation below equal to 1 [image]

and got c = 0.02*exp(0.02)

I checked my work by some lines of code

```
c = 0.02*exp(0.02)
P = 0
for (i in 1:999){
  P = P +  c * exp(-i/50)}
```

The result was 1.01003333098722 but I expected 1. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why did you integrate on $[1, \infty)$ instead of $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: I think when x < 0, f(x) = 0 so I can safely leave it, is that correct?

Comment: No. This is a continuous distribution, not a discrete distribution.

Comment: Friend all computer have precission limits, because of being finites, and you are just doing an approximation of an infinite operation, so sometimes you will get numeric issues.

Comment: Why would that sum equal $1$? Aren't you just approximating the integral, that basically means you'll get approximate results.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thank you, I think I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should handle basic integrations by hand and not rely on computers.

$\int_{0}^{\infty}ce^{-\frac{x}{50}}dx =1\implies -50c(e^{-\infty}-e^{0})=1$.

But $e^{-\infty}=0$ and $e^{0}=1$ .

$50c=1\implies c=\frac{1}{50}$ .

(Normally you are not even allowed to write $\infty$ like that . You have to take limits.) .

For more information look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood it incorrectly and set the lower bound to 1. I calculated by hand and used code to check my answer. Sorry I didn't post my calculations because... I don't know how to write math symbols on this.

Comment: You should mark it as an answer then. and here is a tutorial for mathjax . It is simple enough and since you already know coding , it will be easy and also useful to you in the future. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference